# How to access an ubuntu machine via VNC from the login screen?

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, remote-access, remote-control

I want to access an Ubuntu machine remotely via VNC. But I can access the Ubuntu machine only if the user is logged in. I want to access the ubuntu machine via VNC from the login screen itself. We can access all windows machines from the login screen. However we were not able to access the Ubuntu machine from the login screen. There is some way but I am not aware of the details.  Can someone give a solution to this problem?

Comment: If the other machine is on the same LAN it would be feasible to just use XDMCP instead of VNC. If it's not on the same LAN, unaccelerated X over the network might be too slow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your best bet is to install [xrdp](http://xrdp.sourceforge.net) [image: Install xrdp]. After installation, you can use an RDP client to connect to the machine - you will then be prompted for your credentials as you would be on the login screen.

Comment: I have installed  xrdp but still i am unable to access the ubuntu machine from the login screen.

Comment: @karthick: Are you connecting to the machine with VNC or using an RDP client?

Comment: I dont find RDP client in my machine. Where it will be located ?

Comment: @karthick: Are you using Ubuntu as your client? If so, the program to use is called "Terminal Server Client". On Windows, it's called "Remote Desktop" IIRC.

Comment: Yeah thank you. Is it possible to create a launcher for Terminal Server Client ?

Comment: @karthick: That would make a great question to ask here :)

Comment: Is it possible to create a xrdp launcher ?

Comment: @kar: `xrdp` is a daemon.

Comment: Wow, xrdp is awesome, I had spent hours trying to get xvncserver to work remotely and five seconds after  sudo apt-get install xrpd I was at the desktop!

Comment: Do you want me to install xrdp in all hosts?

Comment: Thankyou i have installed xrdp in all hosts and now i am able to access the ubuntu machine from the login screen.

Comment: Doesn't work. RDP client shows empty XWindow desktop with cross-like mouse cursor, then closes w/o any error message

Answer (score 7):

Overall, [I'd recommend `x11vnc`](https://askubuntu.com/a/481185/19264).

## TL;DR

```
apt-get -y install x11vnc
x11vnc -storepasswd
```

Enter your password, it's saved by default in `~/.vnc/passwd` [in INSECURE encrypted form.  It can be decrypted because the key is known.](https://github.com/trinitronx/vncpasswd.py).. protect it with filesystem permissions)

```
chmod 600 ~/.vnc/passwd
```

Save my helper script locally:

```
mkdir ~/bin/
curl https://gist.githubusercontent.com/trinitronx/76d2bf98489e5e3e84fa/raw/53885d87f91320b574ca4f7d609e4bb268274f68/start_x11vnc.sh  > ~/bin/start_x11vnc.sh && chmod +x ~/bin/start_x11vnc.sh
```

From your VNC Client host:

```
ssh -f  -L 5900:127.0.0.1:5900 -p 22 youruser@your-ubuntu-host.example.com '~/bin/start_x11vnc.sh && sleep 10'
```

Or, from your VNC Server host, run :

```
~/bin/start_x11vnc.sh
```

via a terminal (or start it as a daemon with `-forever` as an [init.d service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init), [upstart service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstart), [systemd unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd), or however you wish)

Now run your VNC Client of choice from your Client Host, point it at: `127.0.0.1:5900`, login with password saved above.

## Use the X11 "Magic Cookie"

Most [X display managers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager_(program_type)) (like [GDM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Display_Manager), [XDM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XDM_(display_manager)), [KDM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDE_Display_Manager)) start an initial X11 server and [authenticate to it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/77315/7688) with an [MIT Magic Cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_authorization#Cookie-based_access).  Depending on your display manager, the magic cookie will be [found in one of various locations](https://askubuntu.com/a/274485/19264).

I've had good luck getting a VNC session open on the Ubuntu GDM login screen <sup>*NOTE1</sup> by finding the magic cookie with [this script](https://gist.github.com/trinitronx/76d2bf98489e5e3e84fa):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
DEFAULT_DISPLAY=:0
X11VNC_DISPLAY="$DEFAULT_DISPLAY"

if [ -x /usr/bin/x11vnc ]; then
     [ "$1" == '-nocache' ] && CACHE_FLAG='-noncache' || CACHE_FLAG='-noncache'
     [ "$2" == '-guess' ] && GUESS_FLAG='-auth guess' || GUESS_FLAG=''
         [ -f /root/.vnc/passwd ] && PASSWORD="/root/.vnc/passwd"
         [ -f $HOME/.vnc/passwd ] && PASSWORD="$HOME/.vnc/passwd"
         [ ! -z "$PASSWORD" ] && x11vnc -display $X11VNC_DISPLAY -xkb -rfbauth $PASSWORD -rfbport 5900 -shared -forever -nowf -norc -notruecolor -bg $GUESS_FLAG $CACHE_FLAG -noxdamage
    EXIT_CODE=$?
     if [ $EXIT_CODE -ne 0 ]; then

        echo "\n*********************************************************************"
        echo "*** Could not start x11vnc!  Trying again with gdm MAGIC_COOKIE! ***"
        echo "*********************************************************************\n"

        # Old GDM location for Ubuntu <= 17.10
        MAGIC_COOKIE_FILE=`sudo find /var/run/gdm/ -iname database | grep for-gdm`

        # New GDM location for Ubuntu >= 17.10
        [ -z "$MAGIC_COOKIE_FILE" ] && NUM_MAGIC_COOKIE_FILE_SESSIONS=`sudo find /run/user/ -iwholename '*/gdm/*' -iname '*Xauthority' 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
        if [ -z "$MAGIC_COOKIE_FILE" -a "$NUM_MAGIC_COOKIE_FILE_SESSIONS" -gt 1 ]; then
            # Find the current user's session
            MAGIC_COOKIE_FILE=`sudo find /run/user/$(id -u) -iwholename '*/gdm/*' -iname '*Xauthority'`
            X11VNC_DISPLAY=":1"
        else
            # Find the GDM user's session (or whichever shows up first in ps list)
            # This should pick up the original gdm session which grabs :0
            # If you login after gdm login screen, your Xorg server may end up on another display!
            # Workaround for now is to restart x11vnc on that display number
            [ -z "$MAGIC_COOKIE_FILE" ] && MAGIC_COOKIE_FILE=`sudo find /run/user/ -iwholename '*/gdm/*' -iname '*Xauthority' | head -n1`
        fi
        # Old lightdm location for Ubuntu <= 17.10
        [ -z "$MAGIC_COOKIE_FILE" ] && MAGIC_COOKIE_FILE=`sudo find /var/lib -name '.Xauthority' -o -wholename '/var/run/lightdm/root/:0' | head -n1`
        #sudo bash -c "[ -z \"$MAGIC_COOKIE_FILE\" -a -e /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 ]" && MAGIC_COOKIE_FILE='/var/run/lightdm/root/:0'
        [ -n "$MAGIC_COOKIE_FILE" -a -z "$GUESS_FLAG" ] && AUTH_COOKIE_FLAG="-auth $MAGIC_COOKIE_FILE"
        [ ! -z "$PASSWORD" ] && sudo x11vnc -display $X11VNC_DISPLAY -xkb -rfbauth $PASSWORD -rfbport 5900 -shared -forever -nowf -norc -notruecolor -bg $GUESS_FLAG $CACHE_FLAG -noxdamage ${AUTH_COOKIE_FLAG}
    fi
fi
```

I can start this script (I called it `start_x11vnc.sh`) anytime via SSH... even before login via the `gdm` login screen.  It launches an `x11vnc` server which I can then connect to over [SSH tunnel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140871/7688). (Use `ssh -L 5900:127.0.0.1:5900` or add `LocalForward 5900 127.0.0.1:5900` to your host's entry in `~/.ssh/config`).

**NOTE1**: In some new distro releases such as Ubuntu >= 17.10, the GDM login X session display is completely separate from the logged in user's X session display.  Therefore, it is necessary to first connect to the GDM X session, login... and finally disconnect and re-connect to the newly started X session.  Why they now do it this way is a mystery, but it broke the old version of this script.

Comment: Does not work. VNC client connects then closes immediately

Comment: @Dims Use the command: `vncviewer <remote_ip>`

Comment: script was broken for new versions of Ubuntu... I updated it with a hack to enable it to work again.  It seems now gdm display session is now separate from the logged in session, so if you are using this script on Ubuntu, it will first take you to GDM login screen, then when you login this X session display goes blank.  Now you need to stop the first x11vnc process and re-run the script again to re-attach to the separate logged in X session & display.

Answer (score 2):

To enable GDM login over a VNC ssh remote connection try with X11vnc. See also [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25189/remote-gdm-login/25192#25192).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it with VNC, if you don't want to use RDP:

1. Install X11VNC  server : `sudo apt-get install x11vnc` (Or through Ubuntu Software Center -> X11VNC Server)
2. Set a password:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /etc/x11vnc
   sudo x11vnc -storepasswd /etc/x11vnc/passwd
   ```

   Choose `y` to save the password.
3. Create an empty file in `/etc/init` called `x11vnc.conf`:

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /etc/init/x11vnc.conf
   ```
4. Paste this into the file:

   ```
   start on login-session-start

   exec x11vnc -xkb -forever -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -display :0 -rfbauth /etc/x11vnc/passwd -rfbport 5900 -bg -o /var/log/x11vnc.log
   ```
5. Save and close
6. Restart Ubuntu

That's it! You should now be able to connect with any VNC client even before login.

Comment: This didn't work.

Comment: @mace Interesting, it had worked for me, maybe its dependent on the Ubuntu version. Unfortunately, I don't remember what version my Ubuntu was when I had done this procedure.

Answer (score -1):

re: try with X11vnc

x11vnc hasn't been updated since september of 2011!!!! There are known bugs and I'm getting popped by one that triggers a stack smash termination of x11vnc any time a pop-up dialogue (such as clicking the 'file' menu on any window) disconnecting the session.

Raspberry pi's can connect to the desktop manager session on :0, why in the hell is this such a problem for Ubuntu?!?! Why is it necessary to rely on an orphaned, 7 year old program to do this on any modern operating system?