# Desktop sharing options for Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, macosx, rdp

I would like to be able to access my office Ubuntu 12.04 machine from home, from a Mac Mini with Mac OSX. I have a VPN and I am able to access my office machine over SSH, so connectivity is not a problem. I browsed other questions, and it seems that there are several options:

- VNC
- XRDP
- FreeNX (haven't heard this one before)
- Are there any other?

I have been using Remote Desktop on Windows before, and I actually like it. Not sure how well is XRDP implemented. I also used VNC several years back, and I didn't like its performance back then - not sure if things have changed since then.

As I said above, the machine I want to access is running Ubuntu 12.04, with Unity. And I am using Unity by choice - I really like it and would like to continue using it :)
The client computer is running Mac OSX (Snow Leopard).

Based on your previous experience what is the best setup for this environment?

Answer (score 4):

I have tested out various VNC server implementations including:

- TightVNC
- RealVNC
- FreeNX
- X11VNC

Overall I'd say that the easiest to setup, good performance on dual-display configurations,  cross-platform support for many clients, and most reliable for me has been `X11VNC`.

FreeNX was very difficult to setup, though it was subjectively not that much better or faster than other solutions I tried, so the payoff wasn't as great as I'd hoped.  FreeNX only worked with *nix clients at the time I tried it, and I needed a cross-platform solution.  It could be that I mis-configured it and speed wasn't optimized for my connection somehow, although I'm not sure.

TightVNC and RealVNC worked reasonably well for me in the past.  TightVNC was great on low-speed connections, while RealVNC was great for a slight bit of extra security (b/c it supported longer passwords w/custom block encryption algorithm). However, I had encountered some issues that made me decide to go with X11VNC.  The first was that I had problems when rebooting a remote system, starting the VNC server again on it, and trying to connect to it when **no X session was already running** (just the gdm login screen).  I was able to fix this with `x11vnc` and [this helpful script](https://gist.github.com/trinitronx/76d2bf98489e5e3e84fa).  The second problem that made me switch was that cross-platform and compatibility with many different VNC clients was also important to me.  Most modern internet connections are fast enough to give a reasonably good experience when connecting to a remote system, even over SSH tunneling.  You can experiment with passing some options when starting the `x11vnc` server to make things snappier if you wish.  Some that I've found are in [my script](https://gist.github.com/trinitronx/76d2bf98489e5e3e84fa).

To set up X11VNC:

1. Run `sudo apt-get update`
2. Run `sudo apt-get install x11vnc`
3. Run `x11vnc -storepasswd` and input a password to protect your VNC from unauthorized access <sup>Note 1</sup>
4. Run `x11vnc -usepw` to start the server <sup>Note 2</sup>
5. Connect to the server with your favorite VNC client <sup>Note 3</sup>

**Note 1:** The password is by default stored in a file: `~/.vnc/passwd`.  This file is encrypted by a symmetric key and a special block encryption algorithm.  However the key and the algorithm are known, so [it is possible to decrypt it](https://github.com/trinitronx/vncpasswd.py) (Please only decrypt your own password and don't be evil).  Treat this file as a key to your computer, and protect it with file permissions of `0600` (`chmod 0600 ~/.vnc/passwd`).

**Note 2:** You may add additional command line arguments if you wish, but this one is required for password protection

**Note 3:** Use SSH tunneling for security.  VNC passwords are sent in plaintext over the network.  To do this you'll create a tunnel with `ssh -L 5900:localhost:5900` and then connect your VNC client to `localhost` on port `5900`.  If you don't care about security, or trust everyone on your network then connect your VNC client to the host directly.

For example:

- Given hostname `foo.local` => connect to `foo.local` on port `5900`
- Given IP `192.168.1.123` => connect to `192.168.1.123` on port `5900`

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu offers a VNC server called "Remote Desktop", actually [vinagre](http://projects.gnome.org/vinagre/index.html) which is a flavor of VNC.

Use the Ubuntu Software Center to install it. The server GUI can be configured to auto start on boot. I have found this version of VNC to work fine. However, I don't know what performance you are expecting or your network conditions. The various compression options (JPG, CopyRect, and color depth)  makes a significant improvement when bandwidth and network response times are detracting from your experience.

I don't know about all the flavors of VNC to give you wisdom about which have various features that you may or may not want. What I know about this one is that it works reliably. Vinagre is accepts connections from various flavors of VNC. I am using TightVNC.

Answer (score 0):

Another big one that's really easy to use and set up is Teamviewer. It's not the best software to use if you are planning on working remotely for long periods of times. It's better for just "viewing". The fact that it's very simple to use and set up makes it easy to run with no setup needed and from any computer (as long as you have your ID number).

[Direct link to Teamviewer for Linux](http://www.teamviewer.com/hi/download/linux.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu by default has remote desktop disabled. You have to  enable it. Click on 'Dash' and search for remote desktop. Click on enable remote desktop and a dialog box will open where it will give you various options to define the method of access, password etc.

Once you enable it, any client machine can accesses it remotely using an agent /  remote desktop client which supports vnc. One of my favorite client which can be installed on Windows, Linux and Mac is Remmina Remote desktop.

Here is the post for installing it on a MAC machine -
http://adrian15sgd.wordpress.com/2012/11/21/remmina-for-mac-os-x-build-instructions/

Hope this helps
Regards