# 14.04 - Remote Desktop/Control to Headless Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: unity, remote-desktop, vnc, rdp, xrdp

Apologies if this has been asked many times, but there seems to be a variety of options for remote desktop onto a headless machine running 14.04 LTS (Desktop)

I don't have much experience with Ubuntu, having used Windows 95% of the time.

What is the best solution for Remote Desktop access to a machine with no Mouse/Keyboard/Monitor, in 1920x1080? I'd like to use the Windows native RDP application, if possible. This is **not** on the LAN, if that makes a difference.

I've read about VNC, XRDP, FreeNX, Teamviewer etc.

This question contains useful info: [Desktop sharing options for Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153648/desktop-sharing-options-for-ubuntu-12-04-with-unity) but it doesn't seem to cover the headless side.

**EDIT: I'd like to use the Unity interface remotely, preferably.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that ¨headless¨ means that you do not have the X.Org Display Server installed, you are not able to login with Remote Desktop, VNC, or another ¨Remote Desktop Program¨.

You have two options.

1. **You could install a graphical environment on the server** (when you are at it´s physical location), then install VNC or XRDP, and use your home computer to connect to that VNC/RDP Server. For VNC, I would recommend the TightVNC Viewer (quick Google search will do), and with XRDP installed, you can connect using Windows´ built-in ¨Remote Desktop¨.
2. **In case that you do not want to install a desktop environment**, you need to install a SSH Server. You can then download a program like PuTTY (Google search), and connect to the IP Address, with your username and password. As SSH Server I would highly recommend the `openssh-server` package, which can be installed by executing the following command: `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`. In case that you are root, you do not have to use sudo. I hope that this will help you getting a little further.

If you have any questions, you can ask them here (if you want), I will try to answer them as soon as possible.

Comment: I'm probably using headless incorrectly, but by that I mean I have no peripherals such as a Monitor.

Comment: Hmm, did you install a normal Ubuntu version, (Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Xubuntu), or Ubuntu Server?

Comment: 14.04 LTS (Desktop), as I said in the question. :)

Comment: Okay, sorry, didn´t noticed that :P ! Anyway, do you have VNC installed on that computer?

Comment: It's a clean, fresh install at the moment.

Comment: Then I would use SSH to login, although I am not sure if that package is installed by default. On my Ubuntu MATE installation it was not. So I guess the only thing you could do is to install a VNC/OpenSSH server on the computer itself directly, which means that you have to connect a keyboard/mouse/monitor/cable. After you installed all that, you can disconnect everything and connect using your main computer. In case that you install a VNC Server to connect to a desktop, or RDP, it´s also a good idea to install the SSH Server, so if the desktop crashes, you can restart it using the console.