# Error/problem connecting (Windows 10 RDP into XRDP)

Tags: 14.04, windows, rdp, xrdp

I am running into another issue where the XRDP is not working. I have been at it for quite some time now and I think that I need help. I believe that it is an issue of the Ubuntu machine not listening on a port.

I followed the guide at http://www.tweaking4all.com/software/linux-software/use-xrdp-remote-access-ubuntu-14-04/.

However, when I go to rdp from windows, I am able to connect and type in username and password but when I do, I get the following error:

```
Connecting to sesman IP 127.0.0.1 port 3350
sesman connect ok
sending login info to session manager, please wait...
srdp_mm_process_login_response:login successful for display
started connecting
connecting to 127.0.0.1 5910
error-problem connecting
```

Could the issue be that my Ubuntu machine is not listening to port 5910? WHat do you guys think? If so, how can I make sure that Ubuntu is listening to port 5910?

Edit:

Ok, so when I run this command:

```
sudo netstat -peant | grep ":5910 "
```

Nothing comes up. When I run this command: `sudo netstat -peant | grep "127.0.0.1"` and I scroll through, I do not see anything connected to port 5910. I believe that i have found a large issue. My question now is how do I set up xrdp to listen to port 5910?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, so i found the command that will solve my issue. Run this command to remove the error

Run `gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false`

Comment: when i run it in the terminal of raspberry pi it wrote "No such schema 'org.gnome.Vino'"

Comment: It gives an error.

Answer (score 16):

I found this one really worked for me.
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1314336

I summarize here the solution:

> I had to remove xrdp, vnc4server, tightvnc, which were all installed in the wrong order. I had to install tightvncserver, then install xrdp.

```
sudo apt-get remove xrdp vnc4server tightvncserver
sudo apt-get install tightvncserver
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

Then restart the xrdp service:

```
sudo service xrdp restart
```

Comment: Now I can login, but it logs out back in 1-2 seconds.

Comment: It works for me. Before seeing this answer I didn't even have any VNC server installed.

Comment: Frustratingly, this worked for me.  I have no idea what changed as I had been using xrdp for months before it went haywire.  Thanks!

Comment: This solution works for me too.

Comment: I had not only to remove the packages, I also needed to purge them (sudo apt-get purge xrdp && sudo apt-get purge tightvncserver) and reinstall them in the indicated order. Plus "allowed_users=anybody" in the /etc/X11/Xwrapper.config file.

Answer (score 8):

**It's not worth it - there is a better & less painful solution:**

## ***X11VNC***

I spent at least 8 hours fighting the battle to connect from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 16 via xrpd and Windows rdp. I tried endless "solutions" that I found posted all over the web.  I made progress, but never managed to fully solve it.  Even if I had, though, it seems that this is weak setup anyway, because:

- You can't use the Unity Desktop, so your rdp has connect you to a completely different OS UI than what you would use as the Ubuntu standard.
- You can't be logged on already with that account.  So if you were have a scenerio where sometimes you work directly on the Ubuntu machine, and sometimes you connect remotely, you'd have to be sure to log out to allow for that remote connection.
- From what've read, once you have this, you have also fight a battle to get a "re-connection" mechanism working to re-enter an rdp session you left.
- You have to manually enter credentials every time you log on.  There is no way to save them on the client end and just connect instantly.

I've used a pile of different remote connection interfaces, and overall nothing beats the ease and quality of Windows RDP yet to my mind.  A such, I was pretty fixated on using that.  After fighting this long enough though, and finally throwing in the towel, I found that VNC pretty much works just as well in this context.

As I said initially, on the Ubuntu side I used "x11vnc".  Refer to these directions for details on getting that fully setup:

[How to setup x11vnc to access with graphical login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229989/how-to-setup-x11vnc-to-access-with-graphical-login-screen)

On the Windows side, I used RealVNC Viewer: https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/viewer/, which I already had installed and setup for a remote connection to a Mac on my LAN as well.

With this setup, I have NONE of the weaknesses outlined above. Further, in full screen mode, the display is just as good as it would be naturally.  I see 0 lag, 0 blurring.  I have a bi-directional clipboard working without any effort to get that...

In theory, you are supposed to be able to stack xrpd and x11vnc.  See: http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=5956
I tried that too, just to see if I could get it to work.  I had no luck with that either.  So I just said the hell with xrpd in the end, uninstalled it, and rolled back all the changes I made to my machine fighting with it (or least so of them).

Unless you have a major reason that you NEED RDP instead of VNC, I strongly recommend going this route I've described instead.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly on the first try. x11vnc in Linux Mint, RealVNC viewer in Windows, worked right away.

Comment: flawless connection from Win10 to RaspberryPi running X11VNC on it.

Answer (score 6):

[This post](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/xrdp-under-debian-9-connection-problem-4175623357/#post5817508) helped me get rid of the issue. I restarted the `xrdp` service afterwards just to make sure too.

> Have you tried creating a file /etc/X11/Xwrapper.config containing
>
> `allowed_users = anybody`

Note that I am using windows 10 to connect debian 9. And I used `Xorg`.

Comment: Same problem here Debian 9.5 and Fluxbox.

Comment: worked for me. default allowed_users was set to console

Answer (score 2):

I struggled some days in this problem (Windows 7 Remote Desktop Connection - XRDP CentOS), and by searching [I found](https://sourceforge.net/p/xrdp/discussion/389417/thread/64949bc2/#a18d) that the simplest solution for **error - problem connecting** is **clear "mydomain\username" login**: before installing packages, kill processes or remove temporary files, just try to connect writing your username **only** in the XRDP request, so **do not save it previously** in the Windows 7 Remote Desktop Connection.

If you are not allowed to clear your username (XRDP always showing a name by default), [clear the RDP connection history](http://woshub.com/how-to-clear-rdp-connections-history/) for the server you are trying to connect, or take this as an opportunity to clear all connection history, this way (Windows side - CMD):

```
@echo off
reg delete "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Default" /va /f
reg delete "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Servers" /f
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Servers"
cd %userprofile%\documents\
attrib Default.rdp -s -h
del Default.rdp
```

And then try again to connect. If it doesn't work, you can try:

1. Keep in mind you should use High Color (16 bits) or higher in Windows RDP; or
2. Access xrdp-sesman.log by PuTTY (`cat /var/log/xrdp-sesman.log`), what will problably show "X server for display **10** startup timeout (...) another Xserver is already active on display **10**", then `vncserver -geometry 1024x768 :10` will show there is a temporary file you can clear, so remove the correct temporary files as explained [here](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?218463-VNC-Server-Warning-localhost-1-is-taken-because-of-tmp-X1-lock) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40684810/6166911); or
3. [Downgrade Tiger VNC](https://thornelabs.net/2013/06/28/rhel-6-fix-xrdp-error-another-xserver-is-already-active-on-display-10.html).

Answer (score 2):

I am very new and I have read bugs and docs regarding this.

All I did to fix this issue was to stop and start xrdp, using these commands:

```
sudo service xrdp stop

sudo service xrdp start
```

Comment: Worked for me. xRDP, was working on port 3350.

Answer (score 0):

Just change: 
/etc/xrdp/sesman.ini
AllowRootLogin=1