# xRDP on Ubuntu Mate 16.04 - error connecting

Tags: 16.04, mate, xrdp, tightvncserver

Fresh install and update of Ubuntu Mate 16.04 on a Dell Optiplex 780.

Connecting from a Windows 10 client.

Installed xRDP directly after and tried to connect from Windows.

Got into the RDP session and entered credentials. Then...

Got this error.

```
Connecting to sesman IP 127.0.0.1 port 3350
sesman connect ok
sending login info to session manager, please wait...
srdp_mm_process_login_response:login successful for display
started connecting
connecting to 127.0.0.1 5910
error-problem connecting
```

Ran this command

```
:~$ sudo netstat -peant | grep "127.0.0.1"
```

And got:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3350          0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN      0          39396       8082/xrdp-sesman
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6010          0.0.0.0:*            LISTEN      1000       93529       19428/2
```

Tried the same with grepping "5910" andit  returned nothing.

Tried removing xrdp then installing tightvncserver first, creating a vnc desktop connection, then installing xRDP since that's how i had it set up before on other computers;

I was using VNC on other computers then discovered xRDP, then installed xDRP, killed the :1 desktops and was able to use xRDP without the slightest hitch.

On this desktop, xRDP service was running just fine by the result of the systemctl check.

Tried connecting then viewed my /var/log/syslog and this was the result:

```
Mar 14 09:20:18 IP-LINSRV3 systemd[1]: Started Session c10 of user admin.
Mar 14 09:20:18 IP-LINSRV3 org.a11y.Bus[19492]: ** (process:19503): WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
Mar 14 09:20:18 IP-LINSRV3 mate-session[19501]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_settings_schema_source_lookup: assertion 'source != NULL' failed
Mar 14 09:20:18 IP-LINSRV3 org.a11y.Bus[19492]: Activating service name='org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
Mar 14 09:20:18 IP-LINSRV3 mate-session[19501]: GLib-GIO-ERROR: No GSettings schemas are installed on the system#012aborting...
Mar 14 09:20:18 IP-LINSRV3 kernel: [ 2536.493204] traps: mate-session[19501] trap int3 ip:7fb46a4309eb sp:7fffcadee2c0 error:0
Mar 14 09:20:18 IP-LINSRV3 org.a11y.Bus[19492]: Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
Mar 14 09:20:18 IP-LINSRV3 org.a11y.atspi.Registry[19508]: SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry
Mar 14 09:20:19 IP-LINSRV3 org.a11y.atspi.Registry[19508]: XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":11.0"
Mar 14 09:20:19 IP-LINSRV3 org.a11y.atspi.Registry[19508]:       after 11 requests (9 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

The first bit of cat /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini reads as follows:

```
[globals]
bitmap_cache=yes
bitmap_compression=yes
port=3389
crypt_level=low
channel_code=1
max_bpp=24
#black=000000
#grey=d6d3ce
#dark_grey=808080
#blue=08246b
#dark_blue=08246b
#white=ffffff
#red=ff0000
#green=00ff00
#background=626c72

[xrdp1]
name=sesman-Xvnc
lib=libvnc.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1
```

Got some ideas from this thread,

[Error/problem connecting (Windows 10 RDP into XRDP)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/797973/error-problem-connecting-windows-10-rdp-into-xrdp)

Which references this one...

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1314336

But, no dice.

Should I be doing something differently in Mate?

Should I be posting this in the other thread?

Help me out, Ubuntu Mates!

---

UPDATE!

Didn't change anything but rebooted. Got the same error the first time, but then...

Now I can log in from the xRDP login prompt fully without the previous errors but get this greyed out, pixelated screen.

[image: Connection into an RDP Session]

And the /var/log/syslog looks like...

```
Mar 14 10:10:23 IP-LINSRV3 systemd[1]: Started Session c6 of user admin.
Mar 14 10:10:24 IP-LINSRV3 mate-session[2455]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_settings_schema_source_lookup: assertion 'source != NULL' failed
Mar 14 10:10:24 IP-LINSRV3 org.a11y.Bus[2446]: Activating service name='org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
Mar 14 10:10:24 IP-LINSRV3 org.a11y.Bus[2446]: ** (process:2457): WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
Mar 14 10:10:24 IP-LINSRV3 mate-session[2455]: GLib-GIO-ERROR: No GSettings schemas are installed on the system#012aborting...
Mar 14 10:10:24 IP-LINSRV3 kernel: [  403.818015] traps: mate-session[2455] trap int3 ip:7f92f62ec9eb sp:7fff11338830 error:0
Mar 14 10:10:24 IP-LINSRV3 org.a11y.Bus[2446]: Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
Mar 14 10:10:24 IP-LINSRV3 org.a11y.atspi.Registry[2461]: SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry
```

cattedout  the .xsession-errors and got this;

```
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
mate-session[1371]: WARNING: Unable to find provider '' of required component 'dock'
grep: /home/admin/.xinputrc: No such file or directory
** (process:1690): WARNING **: Warning: show_on_monitor_number is no longer a valid config option for the current version ofTilda.
** (process:1690): WARNING **: Warning: scroll_background is no longer a valid config option for the current version of Tilda.
** (process:1690): WARNING **: Warning: use_image is no longer a valid config option for the current version of Tilda.
/usr/lib/mate-optimus/mate-optimus-applet:7: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
(nm-applet:1646): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_window_thaw_toplevel_updates: assertion 'window->update_and_descendants_freeze_count > 0' failed
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py:50: RuntimeWarning: You have imported the Gtk 2.0 module.  Because Gtk 2.0 was not designed for use with introspection some of the interfaces and API will fail.  As such this is not supported by the pygobject development team and we encourage you to port your app to Gtk 3 or greater. PyGTK is the recomended python mod
ule to use with Gtk 2.
  warnings.warn(warn_msg, RuntimeWarning)
sys:1: PyGIWarning: Caja was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Caja', '2.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
** Message: Initializing gksu extension...
(nm-applet:1646): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_hash_table_remove_all: assertion 'hash_table != NULL' failed
(nm-applet:1646): nm-applet-CRITICAL **: nma_icons_free: assertion 'NM_IS_APPLET (applet)' failed
(blueman-applet:1634): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_window_thaw_toplevel_updates: assertion 'window->update_and_descendants_freeze_count > 0' failed
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/AppIndicator.py:8: PyGIWarning: AppIndicator3 was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('AppIndicator3', '0.1') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
from gi.repository import AppIndicator3 as girAppIndicato
ERROR:dbus.proxies:Introspect error on org.bluez:/: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did n
ot receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy bl
ocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
ERROR:dbus.proxies:Introspect error on org.bluez:/org/bluez: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Timed
Out: Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out
ERROR:dbus.proxies:Introspect error on org.bluez:/: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Fail
ed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out
Xsession: X session started for  at Wed Mar 14 10:06:10 EDT 2018
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  109 (X_ChangeHosts)
  Value in failed request:  0x5
  Serial number of failed request:  6
  Current serial number in output stream:  8
localuser:admin being added to access control list
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  109 (X_ChangeHosts)
  Value in failed request:  0x5
  Serial number of failed request:  6
  Current serial number in output stream:  8
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
/etc/xrdp/startwm.sh: 3: [: x: unexpected operator
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":11.0".
mate-session[2180]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_settings_schema_source_lookup: assertion 'source != NULL' failed
mate-session[2180]: GLib-GIO-ERROR: No GSettings schemas are installed on the system
aborting...
/home/admin/.xsession: line 1:  2180 Trace/breakpoint trap   (core dumped) mate-session
Xsession: X session started for  at Wed Mar 14 10:07:09 EDT 2018
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  109 (X_ChangeHosts)
  Value in failed request:  0x5
  Serial number of failed request:  6
  Current serial number in output stream:  8
localuser:admin being added to access control list
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  109 (X_ChangeHosts)
  Value in failed request:  0x5
  Serial number of failed request:  6
  Current serial number in output stream:  8
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
/etc/xrdp/startwm.sh: 3: [: x: unexpected operator
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":11.0".
mate-session[2291]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_settings_schema_source_lookup: assertion 'source != NULL' failed
mate-session[2291]: GLib-GIO-ERROR: No GSettings schemas are installed on the system
aborting...
/home/admin/.xsession: line 1:  2291 Trace/breakpoint trap   (core dumped) mate-session
Xsession: X session started for  at Wed Mar 14 10:10:24 EDT 2018
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  109 (X_ChangeHosts)
  Value in failed request:  0x5
  Serial number of failed request:  6
  Current serial number in output stream:  8
localuser:admin being added to access control list
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  109 (X_ChangeHosts)
  Value in failed request:  0x5
  Serial number of failed request:  6
  Current serial number in output stream:  8
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
/etc/xrdp/startwm.sh: 3: [: x: unexpected operator
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":11.0".
mate-session[2455]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_settings_schema_source_lookup: assertion 'source != NULL' failed
mate-session[2455]: GLib-GIO-ERROR: No GSettings schemas are installed on the system
aborting...
/home/admin/.xsession: line 1:  2455 Trace/breakpoint trap   (core dumped) mate-session
```

Comment: Just a quick look... The Xorg server is running but no desktop. You are using VNC server to connect between XRDP and Xorg. VNC must start the display. Example if you booted into command line mode and the command you ran to start the desktop (startx, startlxde, mate-session, ...) must be ran by VNC. FYI: xorgxrdp in place of VNC seems to be more efficient and support screen resizing...

Comment: ok, so i tried on another fresh install of mate, identical. went through the process of setting up tightvncserver first. then connected through vnc (to a greyed out screen). then killed the connection, installed xrdp and was immediately able to connect. however, thereis  a permanent terminal in the upper left hand corner. SOOOO, i think your instinct about it being VNC not properly in some way shape or form starting the desktop up could be correct. maybe i need to get tightvncserver working properly before i get into the RDP business. I will look into xorgrdp to test on the third machine. TNX!

Comment: "connected through vnc (to a greyed out screen)" I think you would want your desktop to load at this point. Go back to the VNC setup and make it connect to the display on the "monitor" or create a new display. If you move the VNC server to the display manager you can log in as any valid user. (lightDM, GDM, ...)

Comment: what setting/config file would i be altering to connect the display (xorg process?) to the "monitor" (VNC virtual desktop?). pardon...terminology gap in understanding.  also how would "move" the vncserver to the display manager? NOOB here. not getting the fundamentals of how the components of x windows are interwoven and utilized. please decode your very informed suggestion when you have a chance. continuing to research away on my end.

Comment: Look at this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391608/run-x11vnc-before-user-login/391625#391625) to setup VNC before login.

Comment: I have some notes on setting up Xrdp for Mint, but I use xorgxrdp. Let me see if I can get it together.

Comment: Look at this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391164/setting-up-cross-platform-vnc-system/391199#391199) on how to setup XRDP on Ubuntu 16+.

Comment: ok, so after further efforts to get this working I discovered that i was overshooting. i eventually got xrdp working, but found that two of my servers were running at different cpu utilization. 1 had vnc4server running with high cpu usage, the other low cpu cycles running tighvncserver. then i saw the one running TVNC had a 3 line xstartup that I have listed above. the VNC4 xstartup had the custom one i found at various sites. both were accepting beautiful 1080p rdp connections on my 24" monitor. so i removed the vnc4 instance and replaced with TVNC and scp'd xsartup over and voila! K.I.S.S.!

Comment: You _may_ get even better cpu utilization using the sesman back end vs VNC server back end, although I personally do not think the login GUI looks as nice as the VNC if started  before login.

Comment: You may add an answer to your own question to help the next person!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wowsers! much easier than I thought.
I just used this simple xstartup directive and boom, low cpu usage and great connection.

```
#!/bin/bash
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
startmate &
```

I was obviously overthinking this and did not go about the setup properly.

Now I know to:

1. install tightvnc
2. start up :1 desktop then kill to create the ~/.vnc directory and configs
3. make sure the xstartup directive is the super basic 3 liner above, and overwrite if necessary.
4. install xrdp
5. start up the :1 desktop again
6. connect using my favorite RDP client, Remmina!
7. try new stuff out, make mistakes, ask you guyziz about it, troubleshoot, and somehow get it working to learn more about how 'Nix works!

Thanks, Ubuntu Mates!