# How to login into xrdp/xorg in hyper-v? When I enter ubuntu login credentials in the input box, a blank blue screen shows up

Tags: 22.04, xorg, virtualization, xrdp, hyper-v

[image]

Disabling the *Enhanced session mode* let's me enter into ubuntu without xrdp login dialogue box but it results in not able to copy clipboard and full screen doesn't work.

I don't have much experience with Hyper-v, Ubuntu and all this virtual machine stuff. Google didn't help either.

Please guide me how to login here and work with Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Do https://askubuntu.com/q/1296796/1004020 , https://askubuntu.com/q/1166568/1004020 , or https://askubuntu.com/q/1404245/1004020 help?