# Openbox vs. LXQt

Tags: 20.04, lubuntu, openbox, lxqt

I have just installed Lubuntu 20.04.
I see this

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config x-session-manager
There are 2 choices for the alternative x-session-manager (providing /usr/bin/x-session-manager).

  Selection    Path                      Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/startlxqt         50        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/openbox-session   40        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/startlxqt         50        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 

$ wmctrl -m
Name: Openbox
Class:
PID: N/A
Window manager's "showing the desktop" mode: OFF
```

**Is there any contradiction in the fact that `update-alternatives` shows `startlxqt` which is likely what is used, and `wmctrl` returns `Openbox`?**

**Is this indicative of any configuration issue?**

**How can this be explained?**

[nobody](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1373336/openbox-vs-lxqt?noredirect=1#comment2363001_1373336): right, openbox is the Window Manager, and LXQt is the session manager. What possibly helped in my confusion is that I didn't know openbox had a session manager.

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --display x-window-manager
x-window-manager - auto mode
  link best version is /usr/bin/openbox
  link currently points to /usr/bin/openbox
  link x-window-manager is /usr/bin/x-window-manager
  slave x-window-manager.1.gz is /usr/share/man/man1/x-window-manager.1.gz
/usr/bin/openbox - priority 90
  slave x-window-manager.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/openbox.1.gz
```

Comment: Do you want to know , that which is better , LXQT or Open box ?

Comment: No, this is the configuration I obtained out-of-the-box, so I am in doubt if this is normal/expected, or it is indicative of any issue with my configuration. I am not looking for anything to choose myself, as of now.

Comment: session-manager != window-manager.  `sudo update-alternatives --display x-window-manager`

Comment: LXQt aims to be a de desktop; it's WM agnostic by design (unlike some DEs that were designed for specific ones), but expects one for full functionality. Lubuntu uses `openbox` for that purpose, but not all do (eg. Debian use `xfwm4` to perform that role with LXQt installs).  You can switch it to another if you desire (see the manual - https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/3/3.2/3.2.13/session_settings.html) though some keyboard shortcuts Lubuntu adds require `openbox` so those will stop working if replaced.  I see no contradiction(s); you're welcome to use `openbox` on it's own (thus the option!)

Answer (score 1):

LXQt is a desktop; it's WM agnostic by design (unlike some DEs that were designed for specific ones), but expects one for full functionality.

Lubuntu uses `openbox` for that purpose, but not all do (eg. Debian use `xfwm4` to perform that role with LXQt installs).

You can switch it to another if you desire (see the manual - https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/3/3.2/3.2.13/session_settings.html) though some keyboard shortcuts Lubuntu adds require `openbox` so those will stop working if replaced.

**I see no contradiction(s)**.  Openbox can be used on it's own if you wish, or LXQt be used with another WM and **not** Openbox.

`wmctrl` of course is looking at the WM component; which is `openbox` for Lubuntu, as it's not a desktop supported feature.

Your issue is comparing/expecting a desktop that is linked to a certain WM (*GNOME with mutter, Cinnamon with muffin*, etc), and LXQt, which is modular allowing end-users to configure it to be used by other components as users decide (Lubuntu just uses `openbox`).

FYI:  *Some LXQt devs don't like `openbox` either; so if they decided to stop being agnostic & link LXQt to a WM, I doubt it would be `openbox`.*