# Unity + headless desktop sharing

Tags: unity, remote-desktop, vnc

I am running Ubuntu Server 16.04 on the Google Compute Engine and I want to install Unity 7.4 desktop over it and connect to it with Google Remote Desktop.

It is my development machine (headless desktop), not a standalone server which neends be minimal. As I work on the go, I am used to work remotely in the cloud. There is no problem with hardware as I can increase the RAM, CPU or HDD as needed.

1. After I install ubuntu-desktop package I am not able to connect SSH 22 to my compute engine instance anymore and I lost control completely and have to recreate new instance (probably should write to Google forum about this)
2. There is no headless Google Remode Desktop installer, so basically I have to install temporary VNC to install Chrome, then configure the Chrome RDP headless service to run on system startup, delete the temporary VNC connection and after that I should be able to connect there anytime with my Chrome client on the go.

I have following questions:

- Is Unity able to work with VNC? I have found only tutorials for XFCE and similar lightweight desktops.
- Is Unity able to work with Google RDP?
- What about performance? There is no 3D graphics card in Google Cloud
- I have LTE on the go, so network should be no problem.
- if impossible to run Unity remotely, which lightweight desktop is closest to it? (I am quite a Mac fan)

**Final Thoughts**
Thanks for the responses. I have ended trying to run Unity desktop in Google Compute Engine bacause of missing GPU. I am switching into some lighter desktop till Google introduces GPU support.

Comment: See [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/229989/how-to-setup-x11vnc-to-access-with-graphical-login-screen) and look for the answer that mentions systemd. Unity also works with Google RDP. Please ask one question at a time.  No 3D graphics card may be  a problem. But I don't know enough about cloud computing.

Answer (score 0):

you could use teamviewer, it doesnt need to beport fowarded and it shows the entire desktop, this includes all DE's, it also works on andriod, ios, windows and mac :)