# vnc XOpenDisplay failed (:0) after installing nvidia display driver and reboot

Tags: nvidia, xorg, vnc

ubuntu 16.04

1. setup vnc. (vnc worked)
2. setup nvidia display driver and reboot
3. try to use vnc but it failed

> sudo x11vnc -safer -localhost -nopw -once -display :0 -auth
>   /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 03/11/2017 21:05:04 -safer mode: 03/11/2017
>   21:05:04    vnc_connect=0 03/11/2017 21:05:04    accept_remote_cmds=0
>   03/11/2017 21:05:04    safe_remote_only=1 03/11/2017 21:05:04
>   launch_gui=0 03/11/2017 21:05:04 x11vnc version: 0.9.13 lastmod:
>   2011-08-10  pid: 1808 03/11/2017 21:05:04 XOpenDisplay(":0") failed.
>   03/11/2017 21:05:04 Trying again with XAUTHLOCALHOSTNAME=localhost ...
>
> 03/11/2017 21:05:04 *************************************** 03/11/2017
>   21:05:04 *** XOpenDisplay failed (:0)
>
> *** x11vnc was unable to open the X DISPLAY: ":0", it cannot continue.
>   *** There may be "Xlib:" error messages above with details about the failure.
>
> Some tips and guidelines:
>
> ** An X server (the one you wish to view) must be running before x11vnc is    started: x11vnc does not start the X server.  (however,
>   see the -create    option if that is what you really want).
>
> ** You must use -display , -OR- set and export your $DISPLAY    environment variable to refer to the display of the desired X server.
>    - Usually the display is simply ":0" (in fact x11vnc uses this if you forget    to specify it), but in some multi-user situations it could
>   be ":1", ":2",    or even ":137".  Ask your administrator or a guru if
>   you are having    difficulty determining what your X DISPLAY is.
>
> ** Next, you need to have sufficient permissions (Xauthority)    to connect to the X DISPLAY.   Here are some Tips:
>
> - Often, you just need to run x11vnc as the user logged into the X session.    So make sure to be that user when you type x11vnc.
> - Being root is usually not enough because the incorrect MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE    file may be accessed.  The cookie file contains
>     the secret key that    allows x11vnc to connect to the desired X
>     DISPLAY.
> - You can explicitly indicate which MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE file should be used    by the -auth option, e.g.:
>        x11vnc -auth /home/someuser/.Xauthority -display :0
>        x11vnc -auth /tmp/.gdmzndVlR -display :0    you must have read permission for the auth file.    See also '-auth guess' and
>     '-findauth' discussed below.
>
> ** If NO ONE is logged into an X session yet, but there is a greeter login    program like "gdm", "kdm", "xdm", or "dtlogin" running, you
>   will need    to find and use the raw display manager MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE
>   file.    Some examples for various display managers:
>
> ```
>  gdm:     -auth /var/gdm/:0.Xauth
>           -auth /var/lib/gdm/:0.Xauth
>  kdm:     -auth /var/lib/kdm/A:0-crWk72
>           -auth /var/run/xauth/A:0-crWk72
>  xdm:     -auth /var/lib/xdm/authdir/authfiles/A:0-XQvaJk
>  dtlogin: -auth /var/dt/A:0-UgaaXa
> ```
>
> Sometimes the command "ps wwwwaux | grep auth" can reveal the file
>   location.
>
> Starting with x11vnc 0.9.9 you can have it try to guess by using:
>
> ```
>           -auth guess
> ```
>
> (see also the x11vnc -findauth option.)
>
> Only root will have read permission for the file, and so x11vnc
>   must be run    as root (or copy it).  The random characters in the
>   filenames will of course    change and the directory the cookie file
>   resides in is system dependent.
>
> See also: http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/faq.html

tried to add script at startup as described in [How to setup x11vnc to access with graphical login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229989/how-to-setup-x11vnc-to-access-with-graphical-login-screen) but no effect

also tried with `-auth guess` but still got

> failed for display=':0'