# Running xdotool on VPS

Tags: scripts, vps

I connect to my VPS using tigerVNC Viewer and run a command like:

```
 xdotool getmouselocation
```

but I always get the error:

```
 Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

On my desktop it is working but not on my VPS

This is how I set up my VPS:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt install xfce4 xfce4-goodies tightvncserver
vncserver
vncserver -kill :1
nano ~/.vnc/xstartup
     #!/bin/bash
     xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
     startxfce4 &
chmod +x ~/.vnc/xstartup
vncserver
sudo apt update
sudo apt install xdotool
```

What can I do?

Comment: Isn't the command supposed to be `xdotool getmouselocation`?

Comment: @Terrance tryed that command, then i tryed more commands but they all say: segmentation fault

Comment: @RapidGainz is there an X server running on that machine? If not, `xdotool` won't work.

Comment: @danzel ive checked and i use graphical.target that is X server right?

Comment: @Terrance won't `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` also work?

Comment: @DKBose Yeah, it is just another way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug/incompatibility between `xdotool` and some VNC implementations, especially `tightvnc`. See [this ~3 years old open GitHub issue on xdotool](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/issues/126).

In the thread the `xdotool` developer [mentions a workaround](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/issues/126#issuecomment-240618974), by building a specific older version of `xdotool` from source:

> As a workaround, y'all can use [`edbbb7a`](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/commit/edbbb7a8f664ceacbb2cffbe8ee4f5a26b5addc8) (from December 2013) as a git commit and is successful on tightvnc:
>
> ```
> % git checkout edbbb7a8f664ceacbb2cffbe8ee4f5a26b5addc8
> % make install
> % DISPLAY=:1 xdotool getmouselocation
> x:320 y:240 screen:0 window:37
> ```

Alternatively, you can try replacing `tightvnc` with e.g. `tigervnc`, which [doesn't seem to have this issue](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/issues/126#issuecomment-240314199).

Comment: I am running `x11vnc` server which also doesn't seem to have this bug.  That would explain why I can't duplicate the issue.  =)

Comment: @RapidGainz I am pretty certain that this is the one I followed for my install:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/229989/how-to-setup-x11vnc-to-access-with-graphical-login-screen

Comment: @Terrance i can finally connect to my vps using vnc by adding a dummy monitor https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78103/cant-start-x11vnc-without-attached-monitor but now it ask for an username and password and i tryed vnc password and my vps name but it wont login :(

Comment: @RapidGainz Ah, yes, the fake monitor works fine.  I ended up adding a monitor to my host just for that reason.  But anyway, in my startup service file my exec line looks like `ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -auth guess -forever -loop -noxdamage -repeat -rfbauth /etc/x11vnc.pass -rfbport 5900 -shared`  And mine only asks for the password.

Comment: [This discussion has been moved to/continued in a follow-up question.](https://askubuntu.com/q/1146655/367990)