# x11vnc on ubuntu vps

Tags: scripts, vps

this is what i did:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt install xfce4 xfce4-goodies
```

installed a video dummy https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/78156

```
x11vnc -storepasswd
sudo x11vnc -xkb -noxrecord -noxfixes -noxdamage -display :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -usepw
```

i can now connect to my vps using TigerVNCViewer but as soon i connect i get a ubuntu screen wich says "failed to start session", i then enter my name and password and it says the same.
 what can i do?

Comment: You are trying to log in with a username and password that is setup on the remote host, correct?

Comment: @Terrance yea the username should be my computer name from the vps and the password should be the VNC password i made using "x11vnc -storepasswd" becouse if i enter anything else than that it just says wrong password