# How to Auto Start VNC - I can launch it from SSH but after a reboot, it doesn't auto start

Tags: startup, vnc

I have gone down a rabbit hole with all of the different ways to do this.  I think I am almost there but something in my auto start is not correct.

Currently via SSH I can get VNC running with this command:

x11vnc -rfbauth /home/username/.vnc/passwd

It calls a stored password and this is working fine.

I have created a x11vnc.conf file in  /etc/init/

For simplicity sake, I only have the following in this file:

exec /usr/bin/x11vnc -rfbauth /home/username/.vnc/passwd

However it doesn't start on bootup.

Any help is appreciated, I'm not very literate with ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to setup x11vnc to access with graphical login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229989/how-to-setup-x11vnc-to-access-with-graphical-login-screen)

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

1. Validate your UID

   ```
    $ id
   ```

   it will return your `uid=xxxx`. In my case it is `1000`.

   ```
    $ id
    uid=1000(ubuntu) gid=................
   ```

   Keep this number handy for the following
2. Modify the `x11vnc.service` file

   ```
    $ sudo vi /lib/systemd/system/x11vnc.service
   ```

   and add the following:

   ```
    [Unit]
    Description=Start x11vnc at startup.
    After=multi-user.target
    [Service]
    Type=simple
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -loop -forever -bg -rfbport 5900 -xkb -noxrecord -noxfixes -noxdamage -shared -norc -auth /run/user/**UID**/gdm/Xauthority -rfbauth /etc/x11vnc.pass
    [Install] 
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```

   Save your file, and remember **to change the UID with your uid number**.
3. Enable as a service:

   ```
    $ sudo systemctl enable x11vnc.service
    $ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
    $ sudo systemctl start x11vnc.service
   ```

That's it !!!

Now reboot and try. Remember that you have to login in order to connect to VNC, otherwise (for security) you will not be able to login.

Also, have in mind that there are other alternatives to VNC, such as TeamViewer or AnyDesktop.