# Can't acces to Xauthority for X11VNC (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: xorg, 20.04, vnc, wayland

I'm trying to implement X11VNC on Ubuntu 20.04 but it's been frustrating.
I need to use command way, the goal is to keep it on a systemd service.

As I know Ubuntu is using Xorg for the moment. Running `ps wwwwaux | grep auth` I get this:

> gdm         3530  0.0  2.4 211180 50128 tty1     Sl+  10:41   0:01 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt1 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/125/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3
>
> admin-r+    4700  0.2  2.7 216112 55220 tty2     Sl+  11:58   0:02 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3

So it should be correct to run the X11VNC server like this when user is not logged in (forget security pls):

```
x11vnc -xkb -noxrecord -noxfixes -noxdamage -forever -rfbport 11226 -auth /run/user/125/gdm/Xauthority -display :0
```

And like this when it's logged in:

```
x11vnc -xkb -noxrecord -noxfixes -noxdamage -forever -rfbport 11226 -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -display :0
```

Well, it works good on GDM, but not when the user is logged in.

- Tried with root and user profile of course.
- UUIDs checked of course.

Also tried with the directive GDM conf file `WaylandEnable=false` commented and without comment. When comment it, it works running this when the user is logged in:

`x11vnc -xkb -noxrecord -noxfixes -noxdamage -forever -rfbport 11226 -display :0`

But not works in GDM.
If I comment it, it works on GDM from root with:

```
x11vnc -xkb -noxrecord -noxfixes -noxdamage -forever -rfbport 11226 -auth /run/user/125/gdm/Xauthority -display :0
```

So I don't get a solution for everything. I'm now out of ideas. LightDM is not a solution, cause we want to use GDM3.

Any response will be highly appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was the display.
As lightdm only uses one display (:0), GDM raises a display for each user, so this should be correct and works for me:

> x11vnc -xkb -noxrecord -noxfixes -noxdamage -forever -rfbport 11226
> -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -display :1

Comment: for a pure LightDM setup with Debian or Ubuntu, the auth path maybe a bit different,
`x11vnc -display :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0` is a good start. 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/229989/how-to-setup-x11vnc-to-access-with-graphical-login-screen/

Answer (score -1):

I've had similar problems. I couldn't login to Ubuntu on the boot screen. and finally came up with a workaround script to fix X11VNC's issues while using the default GDM3 on Ubuntu 21. I wish X11VNC would fix this.

Use this as a setup script to configure your X11VNC after installing x11vnc.

```
    #!/bin/bash


if [ -z "$1" ]; then echo "Please pass the password you would like to use as an argument to this script"; exit 1 ; else echo "Good start.going ahead."; fi

apt update && apt install tmux -y
password=$1
passwordfile='/etc/x11vnc.pass'
servicefile='/etc/systemd/system/x11vnc.service'
timerfile='/etc/systemd/system/x11vnc.timer'
script='/usr/bin/startxvnc'
apt-get update
apt-get install x11vnc net-tools -y
x11vnc -storepasswd $password $passwordfile



cat >$servicefile <<'EOT'
[Unit]
Description="x11vnc"
Requires=display-manager.service

[Service]
Type=simple
#Environment=XAUTHORITY=$(ps aux | grep -o -E "(-auth)(.*)(Xauth)[a-zA-Z]+")
#ExecStart=tmux new -s gj -d '/usr/bin/x11vnc $(ps aux | grep -o -E "(-auth)(.*)(Xauth)[a-zA-Z]+") -display :0 -rfbauth /etc/x11vnc.pass -shared -forever'
#ExecStartPre=tmux new -s x11vnc -d
ExecStart=bash -c /usr/bin/startxvnc
#ExecStop=tmux kill-session -t x11vnc
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=2

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
WantedBy=multi-user.target


EOT


cat >$timerfile <<'EOT'
Unit]
Description=Wait for some time before running X11VNC

[Timer]
OnBootSec=5sec

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target

EOT




cat >$script <<'EOT'
#!/bin/bash

getxauths()
{
xauths=()

ps aux | grep -o -E "(-auth)(.*)(Xauth)[a-zA-Z]+" | (while IFS= read -r xauth
do
xauths+=("$xauth")
done
printf "%s\n" "${xauths[@]}" | sort -u
) }


getpname()
{
#psp=$(ps -p $(lsof -t -i:5900) -o command)
psp=$(cat /proc/$(lsof -t -i:$1)/cmdline)
echo $psp
}

killproc()
{
pkill -9 $(lsof -t -i:$1)
echo "Killed by port $1"
}


starttmux()
{
xauth=$1
        tmux new -s $xauth -d
        tmux send-keys -t $xauth:0 "for (( ; ; )) ; do sleep 3s; ((disp ^= 1)) ; /usr/bin/x11vnc -display :\$disp -auth $xauth -rfbauth /etc/x11vnc.pass -shared -forever ; done" Enter

}

#echo $(getpname)
start() {
for (( ; ; )) ; do

#echo $psp
xauths=$(getxauths)
for xauth in $xauths ; do
xauth="$xauth" | xargs
if [[ ${xauth} != *"-auth"* ]];then
            unset tsessions
            tsessions=($(tmux list-sessions -F '#{session_name}'))

echo "tessions is " ${tsessions[@]} 

echo "xauth is " ${xauth}
        if [[ ! " ${tsessions[@]} " =~ " ${xauth} " ]]; then
starttmux $xauth


psp=$(getpname 5900)
echo $psp | grep -E -o "(-auth)(.*)(Xauth)[a-zA-Z]+" | (while IFS= read -r xold
do
sessionname=$(echo ${xold#"-auth"} | xargs)
#tmux kill-session -t "$sessionname"
        if [[ ! " ${tsessions[@]} " =~ " ${xauth} " ]]; then
            if [[ $psp == *"user/125"*  ]] ; then killproc 5900 ; tmux kill-session -t "$sessionname"  ; echo "session name is $sessionname" ;
             fi ; else starttmux $xauth ; sleep 30s ; fi
done)

        fi

fi


done

sleep 3s
done
}
start
EOT

chmod u+x $script
sed -i -e 's/WaylandEnable=true/WaylandEnable=false/g' /etc/gdm3/custom.conf 
sed -i -e 's/#WaylandEnable=false/WaylandEnable=false/g' /etc/gdm3/custom.conf 

systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable x11vnc.timer
systemctl stop x11vnc.service
systemctl disable x11vnc.service
systemctl restart x11vnc.timer
```

Comment: this solution looks very brittle, and isn't documented enough. 
suggest try the /var/run/xx to get the proper authority file

https://askubuntu.com/questions/229989/how-to-setup-x11vnc-to-access-with-graphical-login-screen/

Comment: sorry, but that didn't work for me on this specific version of Ubuntu.That's what led me to do so much work on the script.