# Connect to Ubuntu 20.04 via VNC before login (with GDM3)

Tags: 20.04, login, vnc, gdm

Good day,

I need to be able to connect via vnc to an Ubuntu 20.04 client, log out via it and log back in. My problem: VNC can not connect when I am in the login screen. I know this is a general problem with GDM, but unfortunately switching to lightdm is not an alternative.

i found this article here where the script in the last post helped me see the login screen, but i get a black screen when i log in. i have to restart gdm3 in a second session to see a desktop.

[How to setup x11vnc to access with graphical login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229989/how-to-setup-x11vnc-to-access-with-graphical-login-screen/1342212?noredirect=1#comment2293203_1342212)

does anyone god an idea how to see the login screen with gdm?

best regards