# How to get xfce to share screen?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, vnc

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 from ISO and got screen sharing (viewing on a Mac) working, but I was disappointed with the laggy performance. So I want to try xfce. I installed xfce, and when I restart I can choose Ubuntu, Ubuntu on Wayland, Xfce session, or Xubuntu session. In either of the last two, I see no way to enable/start screen sharing, and the Mac has no Networks choice in the Finder sidebar, and attempting to "Connect to server" to vnc://[system name] gets an error. If I log in to Ubuntu, I can still screen share to the Mac.

The only thing I've found so far is https://softsolder.com/2011/12/18/enabling-remote-desktop-sharing-in-xubuntu/ where someone says you start by "firing up vino-preferences in a terminal" without any details on prerequisites. (Simply typing "vino-preferences" gets a command not found error.)

So... how to get xfce to screen-share?

Comment: This answer here https://askubuntu.com/a/676978/231142 still works as far as I know for X based Desktops (Not Wayland).

Comment: Thanks, @Terrance but getting into X11 seemed daunting to me as a relative newbie. I was able to get what I needed by piecing together a few things from net search results: --Substitute dconf-editor for the extinct vino-preferences; Session & Startup::Application Autostart to start Vino on logon; and Gnome's Screen Sharing settings to find, after a lot of head scratching, that my sharing attempts were failing authorization because my changing the password in dconf-editor in xfce had blanked it in Gnome's setting which (I guess) takes precedence.