# Debian VNC goes black If I leave It open and I am inactive

Tags: server, remote-desktop, vnc, .desktop, debian

I am having trouble with my VNC Server. The server keeps giving me black screen If I leave the viewer in the background, and don't do anything on the server specifically. If this happens, I can no longer reconnect to my VNC, and I need to restart the server.
This is kinda annoying, and I couldn't find any solutions this time. Any help?
Here is how I launch my VNC on Debian 9.

```
vncserver -geometry 1920x1280 -depth 24 -localhost no -BlackListTimeout 12000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35396/how-to-access-an-ubuntu-machine-via-vnc-from-the-login-screen), you cannot VNC into a box that is sleeping.

I'm guessing you have autologin enabled hence the ability to use it only after a restart.

As referenced from there

> Your best bet is to install xrdp Install xrdp. After installation, you can use an RDP client to connect to the machine - you will then be prompted for your credentials as you would be on the login screen.

Source: [How to access an ubuntu machine via VNC from the login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35396/how-to-access-an-ubuntu-machine-via-vnc-from-the-login-screen)

### ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION

You can likewise configure the instance to not sleep after a couple minutes. This differs based on the distros Desktop Environment.

My example is setting this up in the power menu for Ubuntu running Gnome.

You'd set the blank screen time to never and disable autosuspend.

[image: Short sample of the power menu in ubuntu]