# Send login details to Login Screen via ssh

Tags: ssh, login

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remote login with graphical display manager (GDM, LightDM)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25189/remote-login-with-graphical-display-manager-gdm-lightdm)

I have set up wake up on lan on my desktop machine. What I want now is, when I wake up my ubuntu machine from hibernation, remotely enter login details so I could start desktop session. Everything should be done via ssh or if possible using other methods. I searched the internet and I couldn't find the answer.

Comment: I kinda solved it from the mentioned post. All I need to do now is to setup password to fix the annoying issue

Comment: still issues. I don't know how to set up x11vnc to start at the login screen. It gives the error can't open/find display. When I log in into the machine everything goes smooth. I'll try to google some more, but every help would be appreciated.

Comment: solved! the x11vnc -auth /var/lib/lightdm/.Xauthority -display :0 should have been run as root. so: sudo x11vnc -auth /var/lib/lightdm/.Xauthority -display :0

Comment: That's what `sudo su` does. Note the `root@remote` in my post I linked :) Glad you get it running!

Comment: yes, silly me :) yes, everything is fine :)