# How to programmatically log-in a user remotely

Tags: gnome, ssh, login, lightdm, login-screen

How do I programmatically and remotely (using SSH) log-in a user so that the lightdm login screen closes and loads the user's desktop as thought they had physical typed in their username and password?

I have a vanilla Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop setup, and I'd like to be able to start a desktop application remotely via SSH. I've already accomplished this by specifying `export DISPLAY=:0`, however, the assumes there's already an X-session running.

Edit: I do **NOT** mean VNC/RDP/Nx. I mean *literally* logging in the *physical* terminal, but when you're *not* at the physical terminal. Imagine someone was sitting down in front of your physical Linux computer, and you want to let them log-in, but you don't want to give them your password. Instead, you SSH into the box, and run a script to log them in and start a desktop session.

Comment: Not quite what was asked but you may be also happy with a VNC solution: http://askubuntu.com/a/25192/3940

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try a program designed for ssh remote login. Details can be found here:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/ssh.1.html

Just add the program to startup list and give required params.

Comment: Please see my edit.