# Send current workspace to another computer?

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, remote-control

I have a desktop and laptop, both running Ubuntu 12.04. Frequently when working, I will need to move from the desktop to the laptop and go on the road. Is there any way possible that on the desktop, i could send a current workspace, with windows open, programs up, browser tabs open, to my second computer?

I dont want to work primarily on the laptop, because it is slower, but being able to queue things up on the desktop and send them to the laptop to have ready for when I leave would be unbelievably time saving. I have explored remote desktop, but it seems overkill to send entire video/image stream between the computers when I basically just need to run some commands on the remote computer (i believe?).

Any information would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ssh` with X forwarding (`ssh -l remoteusername -X remotehost`), this will allow you to run individual application on remote machine, not the whole X-windows system. 
See [this page](http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/XoverSSH/X-over-SSH2.html) and [this AskUbuntu solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/25192/27559) for details.