# Can you sign in (Desktop 12.10) user via SSH?

Tags: 12.10, ssh, vnc

I am away from my Ubuntu machine and was working on it via VNC. I had to sign out of a user account and I lost my Ubuntu VNC connection. I am assuming the VNC server is not running since Ubuntu is sitting at the sign in screen.

I still have ssh access to the machine. I was wondering if it is possible to sign into a (desktop) user account via ssh so the VNC server will come back online?

Comment: This may still work in 12.10 (untested): http://askubuntu.com/questions/25189/remote-login-with-graphical-display-manager-gdm-lightdm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by running and `sudo reboot` command from inside of the ssh session I still had access too. Luckily, my system is set to auto sign-in to the main account on the computer, so I had VNC access again after it booted up.