# Three users working simultaneously on Ubuntu DESKTOP 16.04 LTS through remote connection?

Tags: 16.04, remote-desktop, .desktop, multiple-users

I want to install Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 LTS in my computer, it has 64 GB RAM, Xenon Processor.

I want to install other softwares with GUI such as, MATLAB, R Studio etc.

If I install, Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 LTS the way we generally do, and create 2 more users, will all 3 users be able to access their accounts simultaneously and use MATLAB simultaneously.

I can install UBUNTU, but ain't sure about multiple users and accessibility.

I would highly appreciate if someone could help me in this regard.

PS: I want to know whether all three users will be able to use MATLAB or R-Studio simultaneously through remote desktop if I install them in root. Please tell me if it is possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remote login with graphical display manager (GDM, LightDM)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25189/remote-login-with-graphical-display-manager-gdm-lightdm)