# Remote Gui Login vs Remote Desktop Sharing

Tags: server, login, remote-desktop, vnc

I'm trying to set up a remote X login between two Ubuntu 16.04 machines on the same LAN.

I have tried the provided VNC option that comes with 16.04 and while this works it is not want I am looking for.

The VNC solution requires that a user actually be logged in to the remote system and also requires the user be there to accept the session.

Also the performance is limited to that of the remote system.  My remote system (a proliant server) has a very old graphics adaptor and it is painful to use.  VNC just compounds this slowness for extra slowness!!!

What I want is a remote X session with a logon screen and without having to have a user present.

Like connecting an X windows thin client to a remote X system.

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remote login with graphical display manager (GDM, LightDM)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25189/remote-login-with-graphical-display-manager-gdm-lightdm)

Answer (score 0):

The standard way would be X11 forwarding over SSH, but you'll have to login via ssh in order to start the gui.  I'm not sure you'd really want your computer to serve up a login screen to any connection that's not authenticated

Also X11 is painfully slow.  Best you can do is enable compression and a fast encryption cipher like blowfish or arcfour, but that can only do so much.  It's the X protocol that's the problem.  NX protocol is supposed to be much faster

Check out FreeNX or  x2go