# How to allow Desktop Sharing to work after reboot?

Tags: 16.04, vnc

Ubuntu 16.04

I can enable Desktop Sharing and it works great.  If the system is rebooted, I cannot VNC to the login prompt, I have to have someone log in first.  I could enable auto login, but I have heard this may not work if you need CUDA loaded.

Is there a good way to just have a VNC server running all the time where I can use a basic VNC client and connect, login and use the computer?

Comment: I do that with SSH and x11vnc: https://askubuntu.com/questions/25189/remote-login-with-graphical-display-manager-gdm-lightdm