# Xorg Applications not working on Wayland after update to Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: 20.04, xorg, snap, wayland, 20.10

After updating my Ubuntu 20.04.1 to Ubuntu 20.10, Xorg applications won't launch.

I am using the vanilla gnome-session desktop on wayland.

It used to work well before the update, now applications like spotify, freeCAD and signal-desktop won't launch, failing with `Aborted (Core dumped)` (freeCAD) or `cannot open display: :0` (spotify). It seems to me that these apps do not support wayland and should use the xwayland-server.

What I've tried so far:

- these applications have been installed via snap. When I install signal-desktop through apt it works flawlessly. I thus uninstalled all snaps and the entire snapd thing and removed all configuration files (both for snap and the apps) that I could find with `locate`, then reinstalled them but the problem persists
- Blender had the same problem at first, but it somehow works now after I deleted the `~/.config/blender/`directory. I have however not found such directory for the aforementioned apps
- I started an Xorg Session and tried to start the apps, they all worked.

So I guess the issue is somehow related to Wayland and / or snap, but any ideas for further debugging would be appreciated.

--> Do I have to tell the apps which display to use? If so, how?

--> Do I need to change the wayland /xwayland-server and / or snap configurations / permissions?

Comment: Please see my answer over [there](https://askubuntu.com/a/1288329/1068) for a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having the same issue from 20.04 -> 20.10 with snaps like VLC & Spotify.

I did some research and found this: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/apps-wont-run-and-crash-on-gnome-wayland/20322/7

Apparently it's a new "bug". Only workaround is to use X11 for now.

Comment: Yep it's also listed as known issue in the release notes... Crazy to leave such issue unresolved for a major release.
I've ended up installing flatpak packages for the affected apps now since Xorg does not work for me.