# Chromium quit working on upgrade to Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: gnome, snap, chromium, wayland, 20.10

Opening Chromium via the gui has stopped working. When I try via the command line, I get:

```
$ /snap/bin/chromium
[15738:15738:1026/130054.950616:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1426)] Unable to open X display.
```

I'm running Gnome 3 on Wayland. I've got xwayland installed.

Update: this problem seems to effect all my installed snaps.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: The firefox snap on Ubuntu 20.04 is also affected. So are other snap apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1897224) and a fix will be released shortly. If you don't want to wait you can installe the fixed version already like this:

```
$ cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-groovy-proposed.list
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ groovy-proposed restricted main multiverse universe
EOF

$ cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/groovy-proposed
# Configure apt to allow selective installs of packages from proposed
Package: *
Pin: release a=groovy-proposed
Pin-Priority: 400
EOF

$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt --target-release groovy-proposed install libmutter-7-0
```

For more information about these configuration and commands, see in Ubuntu Wiki [EnableProposed](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed).

Answer (score 3):

Probably snap devs broke everything. Sad to see that my clean system became unusable after the upgrade.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1897224

Try running in a terminal:

➜  ~ chromium

if you see:

[27984:27984:1027/121608.484186:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1426)] Unable to open X display.

Then probably we are in the same boat

Comment: +1 - snaps are one of the worst things to happen to Linux in the past decade

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue and error message (similar issue with Spotify on Snap) - It appears to be a general bug running Snap on Ubuntu 20.10 with Wayland - see [Link 1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1897224) and [Link 2](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/apps-wont-run-and-crash-on-gnome-wayland/20322)

As of now the only workaround seems to be that you avoid Wayland (which also has it's disadvantages). On the GDM Login Screen you can click on the gear icon and select "Ubuntu" rather than "Ubuntu on Wayland".

I hope that helps until this issue is fixed.

Best regards,
Daniel