# Spotify Gtk Wayland [Ubuntu 20.10]

Tags: gtk, wayland, spotify, 20.10

I had Spotify working on 20.04, but it doesn't start after the system upgrade to 20.10.

The error message says

```bsh
(base) pawel@lenovo:~$ spotify 
Warning: GTK2 does not support Wayland!
Gtk-Message: 10:58:57.204: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: 10:58:57.204: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"

(spotify:12596): Gtk-WARNING **: 10:58:57.204: cannot open display: :0
```

The problem appeared in other places, but none of the suggested solutions worked.
Reinstalling with either snap or Ubuntu software (with removing the dot files) doesn't help.

When it comes to the display, I am using a Benq monitor connected with HDMI to my ThinkPad.

Comment: Please see my answer over [there](https://askubuntu.com/a/1288329/1068) for a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same issue and error message. The same applies also to Chromium on Snap which gives a similar error message and does not start:

```
daniel@daniel-ThinkPad-X1:~$ chromium
[18129:18129:1027/191918.020804:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1426)] Unable to open X display.
```

This issue is also posted on askubuntu - [Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1287078/chromium-quit-working-on-upgrade-to-ubuntu-20-10)

It seems that this is a general issue affecting all Snap apps running on the new Ubuntu 20.10 on Wayland - see [Link 1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1897224) and [Link 2](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/apps-wont-run-and-crash-on-gnome-wayland/20322)

As of now the only workaround seems to be that you avoid Wayland (which also has it's disadvantages). On the GDM Login Screen you can click on the gear icon and select "Ubuntu" rather than "Ubuntu on Wayland".

I hope that helps until this issue is fixed.

Best regards,
Daniel

Comment: Thanks! It seems like this is something that Ubuntu is already working on. I will wait for the patch to be released.

Comment: Same problem, almost exact same solution on Fedora 33 here. In login password prompt, there is a gear option and "GNOME on Xorg" is the choice that fixes apps like Spotify.