# Spotify dosen't open Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: snap, vlc, gtk, 20.10, spotify

I've had spotify working on 20.04 but it doesn't start after upgrade to 20.10.

The terminal shows :

```
(base) dark@Asassin:~$ spotify
/snap/spotify/43/bin/desktop-launch: line 51: /home/dark/.config/user-dirs.dirs: Permission denied
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/dark/snap/spotify/43/.config/gtk-2.0/gtkfilechooser.ini': File exists
Gtk-Message: 18:08:52.840: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: 18:08:52.840: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"

(spotify:9720): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:08:52.840: cannot open display: :0
```

I've seen [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1287173/spotify-gtk-wayland-ubuntu-20-10) question but i use normal Ubuntu but it does not help..

I've also installed libatk-adaptor and libgail-common  but it gives same error.

UPDATE:
I've noticed that othor snaps like bingwall, foliate, picard, vlc also doesn't work. it just shows cant connect to desktop or insufficient resorces

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`?

Comment: @Kulfy -rw------- 1 dark dark 633 Mar 6 2020 /home/dark/.config/user-dirs.dirs

Comment: Try running on Wayland instead of Xorg, or vice versa. I only experience this issue on Xorg.

Answer (score 0):

probably the directory is owned by another user

try `sudo chown -R dark:dark /home/dark/.config/` and run `spotify` again

Comment: i am the only user..