# I can't seem to open snaps, other than LibreOffice, when I'm in Ubuntu Wayland. Ubuntu Zorg works fine. (Ubuntu 20.10)

Tags: xorg, snap, wayland

I'm absolutely new to AskUbuntu, and I'm having a problem.
I can't seem to open snaps, except LibreOffice, when I'm in Ubuntu Wayland. Zorg works just fine. I use Ubuntu 20.10.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xorg Applications not working on Wayland after update to Ubuntu 20.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286646/xorg-applications-not-working-on-wayland-after-update-to-ubuntu-20-10)

Comment: This is due to a bug introduced by Ubuntu 20.10, see discussion here: [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286646/xorg-applications-not-working-on-wayland-after-update-to-ubuntu-20-10). And see known issues in 20.10 release notes: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/groovy-gorilla-release-notes/15533
You'll have to wait until they fix it with an update or use flatpak / apt packages instead, if you want to stay with wayland

Comment: @SimonI thank you so much, I got it now.  :D